# Getting definite type instead of combined type for tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following sample code:

```js
const person = {
  name: "abc",
  age: 123,
  isHere: true
};

const getPersonValues = () => {
  return [person.name, person.age, person.isHere];
};

const [name] = getPersonValues(); // type for "name" is string | number | boolean
```

The type for name shows up as `string | number | boolean` here, but I would like it to be a string. Is there a way to do this without having to explicitly declare the definite type inside of `getPersonValues`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force an array to have a tuple type using `as const`. This also makes the type `readonly`, but if just you're using it for destructuring the return value then that's no problem.

```
const getPersonValues = () => {
  return [person.name, person.age, person.isHere] as const;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4XDAvDA3gWAFAwxgCGAtggFwwBExARsNQDT6HEDmlMAjAEwDMLAjACWEABLIuUJAFcE+AL4BufPlCRYnKAAVkqMADViAG3kQMMABQBKDAD5srGEgRRZSMDADaiFOAA6EnImeH1AjgRQvwMAsUlXAF0YYgsNaFU8FTU8ADNZMGAoETQoBGhbJ2EAemr4WVgoAAsxUS9iGAATEVzcqTBYCFBEGFyQJC6EUnBoJGJitDgPOBAIcqFCWpgQZuQAdzEEGF3XGAOTExg6I+IvZCRxlLoQBpcEToRgE2IkETB2M5-TogPZBMgKYTpWDeYIIZKYbR6fxGUzmWyZRT4IA)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

In this case, TypeScript see possible types in array and return it as `Array<string | number | boolean>`.

You need to make it more specific.

```
const getPersonValues = () => {
    return [person.name, person.age, person.isHere] as [string, number, boolean];
};
```

Comment: No need for a type assertion; just annotation the return type like `(): [string, number, boolean] => { return ...; }`

Comment: It does not matter much. Whichever is prefers

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to return as an object:

```ts
const person = {
  name: "abc",
  age: 123,
  isHere: true
};

const getPersonValues = () => {
  return person;
};

const {name, isHere} = getPersonValues(); // name as type 'string', isHere as type 'boolean'
```